# How to write a KQL query in Azure application insights to get the requests percentage?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql

I have asp.net web APIs.I want to write a query in the Azure portal which should show the API endpoints usage by percentage. So that I will know which endpoints are called most and which are called less.

I have written the below KQL query, But it gives the below error when I run it.

**Query:**

```
requests
| summarize count() by operation_Name
| extend percentage = todouble(count_) * 100.0 / todouble(todynamic(summarize count()))
| project operation_Name, percentage
| order by percentage desc
```

**Error:**

> Query could not be parsed at 'summarize' on line [3,73]
>
> Token: summarize Line: 3 Position: 73 If the issue persists, please
> open a support ticket. Request id:
> 8727eeab-aa0a-4ef5-a7e4-58e699419cdd

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your attempt to use the `summarize` operator inside the `todynamic()` function is odd/wrong.

if I understood your verbal description correctly, you may the find the following useful - using [`toscalar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/toscalarfunction):

```
requests
| summarize count() by operation_Name
| extend percentage = 100.0 * count_ / toscalar(requests | count)
| project operation_Name, percentage
| order by percentage desc
```

Comment: when I try by declaring a variable, it doesn't work for me `let total_requests = toscalar(requests | count)`. it gives error. why?

Comment: if you need help with a specific error, you are expected to provide the details of the error

Comment: I’m able to solve the issue. By the way why have you downvoted both questions without reason? That’s not fair